# Working WAR in Tomcat fails in WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I have a `JAVA WAR` file previously exported using JDK 7

I successfully deploy it in `Tomcat 7`, going to `bin\startup.bat`

When trying to do the same in `WildFly 8` (using `bin\standalone.bat`) I get an error:

I guess the relevant error is

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException from
>   [Module "deployment.SpringHelloWorld.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]

Full log:

> 2015-08-12 17:28:51,552 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC
>   service thread 1-16) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SpringHelloWorld:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SpringHelloWorld:
>   Failed to start service   at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_51] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown
>   Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:125)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:509)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:88)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]   ... 3 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException from
>   [Module "deployment.SpringHelloWorld.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   ... 30 more
>
> 2015-08-12 17:28:51,569 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address:
>   ([("deployment" => "SpringHelloWorld.war")]) - failure description:
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SpringHelloWorld"
>   => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SpringHelloWorld:
>   Failed to start service
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException from
>   [Module \"deployment.SpringHelloWorld.war:main\" from Service Module
>   Loader]"}} 2015-08-12 17:28:51,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed
>   "SpringHelloWorld.war" (runtime-name : "SpringHelloWorld.war")
>   2015-08-12 17:28:51,599 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller
>   Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report JBAS014777:   Services
>   which failed to start:      service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SpringHelloWorld:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./SpringHelloWorld:
>   Failed to start service

Both web server installations are clean and have no customization at all

*As one could have guessed, I have little recent experience with Java.*

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The problem was a mixture of v3.1.2 spring-beans with 4.x.x version of other spring jars. Upgrading spring-beans to the same version as the other jars resolved the exception. It's still unclear why it worked in Tomcat.

Does your war contain spring-beans jar? The class that it can't find, `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`, is defined in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans

Comment: uncompressing my WAR i can find it at WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: There is no org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException in that version. I just downloaded it and checked http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.1.2.RELEASE Looks like you might be mixing versions of different Spring jars

Comment: Just read the comment now. I'll try to check if i should be using spring 3.1.2; Anyway it's a mistery why tomcat does not complain

Comment: I can't explain that. I was thinking maybe Tomcat is using some spring libraries internally, and they get loaded first, but doesn't seem likely.

Comment: It seems your first guess was correct. I had some spring jar in versio 3.1.2 and others in 4.1.5;
After updating everything to 4.2.0 it worked

Comment: Glad to hear your problem was resolved! I updated my answer.